# Is there a confirmed way to add a product to the cart using URL in magento 1.8?

Tags: product, cart

There are loads of articles and posts about doing this in previous versions using several different URL strings, all of which none work in Magento 1.8

Has anyone actually figured out a way to do it yet?

For example, this is listed on the Magento Wiki and was added in 2010:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

```
/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

However when clicked, this link just refreshes the cart.

Just incase anyone wants to see how I'm trying to code it:

```
<button type="button" title="Add Loan Phone" class="button" onclick="setLocation('URL HERE')"><span class="green">Add a Loan Phone (+£10)</span></button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the checkout's `cart` helper for that

```
echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

Make sure $_product is an instance of the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

So putting it all together as requested

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([product id]);?>

<button type="button" title="Add Loan Phone" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>')"><span class="green">Add a Loan Phone (+£10)</span></button>
```

Comment: Where can I enter what product ID i want to add?

Comment: Also, when I add your line in the URL HERE part, it just breaks and doesn't show anything below that line. I then removed the setLocation bit, and pasted it with opening and closing PHP tags in the onclick value.. and it still does the same thing. How am I supposed to place that text?

Comment: Can you use the line i pasted in m question, and put your code where it should be please? Many thanks :)

Comment: Updated the answer with the full code as requested!

Comment: Can you define a quantity using this method?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can always try and add a qty parameter. If not use a post method